# Setting a property in a derived class that points to a different field

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm wondering if there's a way to do this, and I don't quite understand why it's not working.  Full disclosure, this is in Unity, so it may be something resolved in a later version of C#.

I have class `Foo`.  `Foo` has a field and property:

```
MeshRenderer meshRenderer;
public MeshRenderer Renderer {get {return this.meshRenderer;} set {this.meshRenderer = value;}}
```

I have a derived class `Bar`.  `Bar` has a field and property:

```
SkinnedMeshRenderer skinnedMeshRenderer;
public SkinnedMeshRenderer Renderer {get {return this.skinnedMeshRenderer;} set {this.skinnedMeshRenderer= value;}}
```

`Foo` has a method, `Remesh()` that sets:

```
this.Renderer.materials = SomeListOfMaterials.ToArray();
```

`Bar`, of course, inherits this method.
Both `MeshRenderer` and `SkinnedMeshRenderer` have a public materials field that takes an array of materials. When I debug into the code, a call to `Bar.Remesh()` falls through to the `Foo.Remesh()` method as expected, and `this.Renderer.materials` is valid as expected, and `SomeListOfMaterials` is a list of materials, as expected. But it comes back with a null reference exception.

If I copy the `Remesh()` code verbatim into `Bar` (with the new modifier), it works fine. When it's falling through to `Foo.Remesh()`, I even checked that this is actually `Bar` (it is).

Answer (score 1):

Edit I think I understand now:

In foo this.Renderer is the MeshRenderer and in bar this.Renderer is the SkinnedMeshRenderer, so when you call Remesh() from the base class its pulling the MeshRenderer but when you add Remesh() to Bar, this.Renderer calls skinnedMeshRenderer. I think you should just add Remesh() method to Bar as a overrided method as you are now working with a SkinnedMeshRenderer instead of a MeshRenderer.

```
this.Renderer.materials = SomeListOfMaterials.ToArray();
```

edit part two to keep code clean

foo

```
Renderer renderer;
public Renderer Renderer {get {return this.renderer;} set {this.renderer = value;}}
```

bar dont change renderer method, MeshRenderer and SkinnedMeshRenderer both derive renderer, so you should still be able to set a MeshRenderer in foo and  a SkinnedMeshRenderer in bar, thus you can just keep Remesh() in foo and it will be valid without overriding in bar.

Comment: You can, and I successfully do. In fact, it works fine in both Renderer types. The entirety of the mesh and material are programmatically generated, and pushing the materials list as an array to materials works quite well. Except in the noted instance of fall through to the base class.

Comment: Okay my bad I think I understand it now, I updated my answer

Comment: yeah, I was just trying to avoid the maintenance overhead given that functionally, the method is identical. It’s seems strange to have to override a method that’s exactly the same. Plus, the method doesn’t really “know” what the Property is, insomuch as it verifies that it accepts the assignment type. And both do. On the surface it seems like what you’re saying, but reasonably it doesn’t seem as if that should matter based on how inheritance works in C#.

Comment: my syntax may be off but I put something else for you to try to keep code clean

Answer (score 0):

`Bar.Renderer` is shadowing `Foo.Renderer`, which property you access depends on the variable you access them through.

If they are supposed to be the same instance, then `Bar` should store its Renderer in the same base field;

```cs
public SkinnedMeshRenderer Renderer {get {return (SkinnedMeshRenderer)base.Renderer;} set {base.Renderer = value;}}
```

Comment: Oooooooo... interesting. So despite invoking new, the base class still sees its own Renderer?  I will give this a shot. Thanks.